# Why are two figures showing up

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

info = {"Quiz":[1,2,5,4,3,2,6,5,7],
        "Score":[1,6,4,2,8,9,10,5,7]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
sns.catplot(x="Quiz", y = 'Score', data=df, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

This is what I am seeing.

[image]

Why are there two images showing?

Comment: Remove the `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))` and the `ax=ax`.

Comment: Alternatively use a stripplot, `sns.stripplot(x="Quiz", y = 'Score', data=df, ax=ax)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation, catplot doesn't return an ax object.